# How do I achieve a curved line that gets thicker at one end in Sketch

Tags: vector, sketch-app

I'm using Sketch to create a logo and I need to draw a curved line with one end thicker than the other.

I've tried using multiple lines but it looks awful.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Curved line using sketch]

Any ideas or tips?

Comment: you must very likely wait some time for a proper answer. Most of us are not Sketch users and the web seems to hold no articles of variable width strokes or "borders" as they say for Sketch app. But you can draw your strokes as closed shapes with no border. You can use boolean subtract for ellipses. Your problem would be nonexistent in Illustrator or Inkscape. Both of them have known a long time variable width strokes, the width and the route of a path can be edited independently. Also the width profile can be defined as a brush or pattern along a path for consistent strokes in the same drawing

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Much appreciated.